# Does laravel 5.5 changes to has also reflect blade

Tags: laravel

I am currently upgrading Laravel 5.4 to 5.5 and I saw this:

*The has Method
The `$request->has` method will now return true even if the input value is an empty string or  null. A new `$request->filled` method has been added that provides the previous behavior of the has method.*

Does this also apply to blade files?

Eg

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">



@if(session()->has('success'))
  <script type="text/javascript">x</script>
@endif
```

And also does it affect files too? Eg

```
if ($request->hasFile('images') == false) {
       //No image..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**no change on any of these from version 5.4 to 5.5**

session()->has('success')

$errors->has('email')

$request->hasFile('images')

**changed from  version 5.4 to 5.5**

$request->has('something');

> Below source codes are from the official github tags

**Here is the `Illuminate\Http`'s (for $request)**

http `has()` method has been changed

`has()` from [5.4](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/v5.4.0/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php)

```
/**
 * Determine if the request contains a non-empty value for an input item.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    $keys = is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args();
    foreach ($keys as $value) {
        if ($this->isEmptyString($value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`has()` from [5.5](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/v5.5.0/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php)

```
/**
 * Determine if the request contains a given input item key.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    $keys = is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args();
    $input = $this->all();
    foreach ($keys as $value) {
        if (! Arr::has($input, $value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`hasFile()` is same

`hasFile()` from [5.4](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/v5.4.0/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php)

```
/**
 * Determine if the uploaded data contains a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasFile($key)
{
    if (! is_array($files = $this->file($key))) {
        $files = [$files];
    }
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($this->isValidFile($file)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`hasFile()` from [5.5](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/v5.4.0/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php)

```
/**
 * Determine if the uploaded data contains a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasFile($key)
{
    if (! is_array($files = $this->file($key))) {
        $files = [$files];
    }
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($this->isValidFile($file)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Here is the `Illumnate\Session`'s (for `session()`)**

session `has()` method is same

from [5.4](https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/5.4/Store.php)

```
/**
 * Checks if a key is present and not null.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    return ! collect(is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args())->contains(function ($key) {
        return is_null($this->get($key));
    });
}
```

session from [5.5](https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/5.5/Store.php)

```
/**
 * Checks if a key is present and not null.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    return ! collect(is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args())->contains(function ($key) {
        return is_null($this->get($key));
    });
}
```

**Here is `Illuminate\Support`'s MessageBag.php (for $errors)**

`has()` from [5.4](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/v5.4.0/MessageBag.php)

```
/**
 * Determine if messages exist for all of the given keys.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $this->any();
    }
    $keys = is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if ($this->first($key) === '') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`has()` from [5.5](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/v5.5.0/MessageBag.php)

```
    /**
 * Determine if messages exist for all of the given keys.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $this->any();
    }
    $keys = is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if ($this->first($key) === '') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```